# How can I create a persistent name for a device on OpenWrt?

Tags: openwrt

When I connect an Arduino to my OpenWrt router it is assigned a device `/dev/ttyUSB<n>` where `n=0,1,2...`  typically `/dev/ttyUSB0`.  The assignment clashes with my 3G mobile dongle which also gets `/dev/ttyUSB<x>` (a different number) but this leaves the ppp driver trying to talk to the Arduino.

I would like to create specific aliases `/dev/ttyArduino` and `/dev/ttyMobile` that I can then use in my configuration.

Under most Linux systems I could do this by creating a udev rule, but openwrt (Barrier Breaker 14.07) runs something other than udev so does not have `/etc/udev/rules.d`.

What is the correct way to create persistent aliases for devices under OpenWrt?